# Google Feed API - How can I achieve continuation with that JSON api?

Tags: json, api, feed, google-reader

For unofficial google reader api, we can use Atom feed api and also can use parameter &c= to continuous get old items.

Google Official Feed API has two kinds: Find and Load

for Load API with JSON, it seems it only allow you load up to 100 newest items from a feed. And there is no parameter like &c=

What if I want item 101 - 1000?

(I try to use this official feed api because I want JSON for higher efficiency than Atom.)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do that using the Google Feeds API, but you can get feed items as JSON from the unofficial Google Reader API. The endpoint is `http:://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/feed/{escaped URL}`. The result contains a "continuation" element, which you can use to request additional items. Authentication should not be neccessary as long as you don't request Google Reader per-user data (such as starred items).

You can find more documentation on the arguments to this endpoint (and some others) in Mihai Parparita's [unofficial Google Reader API documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki).